# Не работает аннотация

Tags: java, spring, валидация, аннотации

Есть приложение, в котором не работает валидация одного поля сущности. Суть её работы заключается в проверке на уникальность по значению поля среди записей в базе данных. Аннотация

> @Validation

из пакета

> org.springframework.validation.annotation;

Находится в контроллере

```
@ResponseBody
public JsonResponseWrapper createCardProduct(@Validated @RequestBody CardProductDto dto) throws BusinessLogicException {
    dto = cardProductService.save(dto);
    accessLogService.create().item(ItemType.CARD_PRODUCT).id(String.valueOf(dto.getId())).type(AccessType.CREATE)
            .fields(dto.getCode(), dto.getRangeStart() + "-"+dto.getRangeEnd(), dto.getBankDto().getCode(), dto.getCardProductType().name(), dto.getScheme().name())
            .save();
    return JsonResponseWrapper.success(dto);
}
```

Когда в контроллер поступает dto вида

```
public class CardProductDto extends IdentifierDto<Long> implements Dict{

@NotNull
private BankDto bankDto;

@UniqueIdentifier(service = CardProductService.class, message = "{cardproduct.validation.name.size}")
@Size(max = 8, message = "{cardproduct.validation.code.size}")
@NotEmpty
private String code;

@Size(max = 255, message = "{cardproduct.validation.name.size}")
@NotEmpty
private String name;

@Size(max = 255, message = "{cardproduct.validation.descr.size}")
private String description;

private CardProductScheme scheme;

@Pattern(regexp = "\\d{6,19}", message = "{cardproduct.validation.range.size}")
@NotEmpty
@NotNull
private String rangeStart;

@Pattern(regexp = "\\d{6,19}", message = "{cardproduct.validation.range.size}")
@NotEmpty
@NotNull
private String rangeEnd;

private CardProductType cardProductType;

private String imgAssetId;

private boolean contactlessSupported;

private boolean dsprSupported;

private String registrationDate;

private String updateDate;

private boolean active;
```

то все аннотации типа @Size @NotEmpty отрабатывают корректно, а аннотация @UniqueIdentifier по какой-то неизвестной мне причине не работает

Аннотация @UniqueIdentifier

```
@Target({ ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE, ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.FIELD 
})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = UniqueIdentifierValidator.class)
@Documented
public @interface UniqueIdentifier {

public String message() default "{not.unique.entity}";

public Class<? extends GenericService> service();

public Class<?> [] groups() default {};

public Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

Её реализация

```
public class UniqueIdentifierValidator implements ConstraintValidator<UniqueIdentifier, String> {

private GenericService genericService;

@Override
public void initialize(UniqueIdentifier constraintAnnotation) {
    if (genericService == null) {
        genericService = ApplicationContextHolder.getBean(constraintAnnotation.service());
    }
}

@Override
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public boolean isValid(String value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
    return !genericService.isExists(value);
}
}
```

Прошу помощи у знающих, т.к сам не очень разбираюсь пока в этом. Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Расскажите подробнее. Опущен момент с конфигурацией бинов. Если делаете по аналогичному примеру - [journaldev.com spring-validation-example-mvc-validator](http://www.journaldev.com/2668/spring-validation-example-mvc-validator), то проследите конфигурацию и использование бина employeeValidator.
Например в контроллере присутствует следующий метод:

```
@InitBinder
private void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
    binder.setValidator(validator);
}
```

По всей видимости у вас отсутствует конфигурирование самого бина валидатора и его привязка к данным